# Easter eggs in Ubuntu

Tags: easter-egg

I just found out about the **free the fish** easter egg available in Ubuntu:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Enter this:  **free the fish**

Are there any more easter eggs available in Ubuntu? What are they?

Comment: Lets not call her "that fish", please. :) She's "Wanda the fish". Wanda is a very nice and smart friend of us. She sits on my top panel in the form of a GNOME applet and she's a part-time fortune teller. Wanda has even a [fan page](http://jrong.tripod.com/wanda.html). She was here long before "Paul the Octopus" and is here after Paul, as well.

Comment: Try this in Ubuntu 11.10 and be disapointed :) (Also an easter egg!)

Comment: Aren't list questions generally not constructive? The part about the removing the fish is constructive, though.

Comment: Too bad we won't get any in Kubuntu: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72331

Comment: Not all of them are easter eggs, but this is a nice list: http://www.tecmint.com/20-funny-commands-of-linux-or-linux-is-fun-in-terminal/

Comment: Is this gnome specific?  Cuz I'm on 14.04 and it brings up "There's no easter eggs in Unity "

Comment: specific question about stopping the fish, http://askubuntu.com/questions/41984/how-do-i-stop-the-free-the-fish-easter-egg?rq=1

Comment: sadly there is no free the fish anymore. Do unity have any Easter egg?

Answer (score 35):

Here is another package that is just a joke : **sl**, standing for *Steam Locomotive*.

Just download [sl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/sl) and then run `sl` in a terminal.

It has been designed for people confusing `ls` and `sl`. See manual page for more exciting features!

Comment: It's really good, I just don't understand how people can get ls wrong? It sounds like `LiSt`, and the keys are on opposite sides of the keyboard.

Comment: It's not about getting confused, but when I type quickly, sometimes it hit sl instead of ls.  As they are both on the ring finger

Answer (score 32):

Watch Star Wars in terminal `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl`

Comment: not really an Ubuntu easter egg but still really cool :)

Comment: That is the most awesome easter egg I have ever seen.

Comment: how to close it in middle without closing terminal directly

Answer (score 27):

Not gonna spoil it for you with a screenshot, but in a terminal try: `apt-get moo`

And then, if you have [`aptitude`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/aptitude) [image: Install aptitude] installed take a look at:

```
aptitude moo
aptitude -v moo
aptitude -vv moo
aptitude -vvv moo
(etc)
```

(Bonus: if you enjoy this then install [`cowsay`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cowsay)[image: Install cowsay]  for hours of command-line entertainment!)

Comment: [Here](http://www.eeggs.com/items/36008.html) is an interesting comment written by **3M-TA3**:
*"Moo!" could have come from the dial up BBS days 'before the 'internet.' On the [Citadel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citadel_%28software%29) BBS system if you pressed the "M" key it responded with "Moo!" It was replaced with "Meet User in later versions. However "Moo" could have come from something in the CP/M operating system, which could lead back to Unix.*

Answer (score 26):

For 11.04 and earlier:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Type in `gegls from outer space` and hit enter.

Comment: I can view the application in Turkish. Someone has translated it. Its interesting for an easter egg to have translation files.

Comment: This is crazy hard!

Comment: In Unity, when I enter this, I get "Still no easter eggs in Unity"

Comment: `gegls from outer space` crashes something; the effect is the same as killing `explorer.exe` in Windows. I had to do CTRL-ALT-DELETE to get out. :(

Answer (score 17):

I just found a quite funny mix between "cowsay" and "fortune":
First, install both cowsay and fortune

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay fortune-mod
```

Now, pass fortune as the argument for cowsay:

```
fortune | cowsay
```

A cow will now tell you something clever about life ;) Have fun!

[image]

Comment: a funny thing with `cowsay` is that there's multiple "cows" - you can try to enter for example `cowsay -f tux "Hello, world"`. A full list of cows is available by running `ls /usr/share/cowsay/cows`. You can also replace `cowsay` with `cowthink` if you want a thought-bubble instead of a speech-bubble :)

Comment: `echo 'asdf' | cowsay | shuf` is great for masochists

Comment: I wonder how painful `cowsay | cowsay | cowsay` is

Answer (score 13):

Lord of The Rings Easter Egg

1. Open Terminal
2. type **`calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.lotr -A 365`** and hit Enter

[image: LoTR Easter Egg]

---

You can also try these

**`calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.pagan -A 365`**

**`calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.music -A 365`**

**`calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.computer -A 365`**

**`calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.history -A 365`**

You can get a list of all calendars available by:

**`ls /usr/share/calendar/`**

Answer (score 12):

```
apt-get moo
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Python

```
import this
```

[image]

Comment: Also - `import antigravity`

Answer (score 10):

In Firefox, go to about:robots

OO.org (doesn't work in LO rc4 on MAverick): http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Easter_Eggs

Answer (score 9):

Clicking on the fish with the mouse will make it go away, to get rid of it for good. you can type `killall gnome-panel` into the terminal. Also, as an easter egg, it is an undocumented feature.

BONUS:
Did you know that, the US Federal Government will not use any software that has undocumented features (aka Easter Eggs)?

Comment: The fish comes back after some time. :)

Comment: Where did you find that documentation ?

Comment: okay maybe it isn't documented as I originally thought, let me fix that.

Comment: Can you link to a source of the Federal Government point? It's interesting.

Comment: This answer is almost four years old and I have no idea :-p

Answer (score 8):

**The meaning of life**

In vim type `:help 42` in the command field

Answer (score 4):

You can see some ubuntu easter egss in the links below..

http://blog.fasttracksites.com/index.php?p=viewentry&id=5

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=91625

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=83137

Answer (score 4):

Try to install `emacs` and then press *ESC+x* (when you've started emacs) (M-x) and then write butterfly for some advanced butterfly magic ;)

Answer (score 4):

I also found a couple too, check them out.
Tested and working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

#### 1. aafire - burn up your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libaa-bin
aafire
```

#### 2. oneko - have an animal chase your cursor.

```
sudo apt-get install oneko
oneko
```

#### 3. xeyes - have a pair of eyes follow your cursor around.

```
xeyes
```

#### 4. cmatrix - the matrix code on your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install cmatrix
cmatrix
```

#### 5. bb - well, it does interesting stuff

```
sudo apt-get install bb
bb
```

Comment: It can be argued that the entire libaa is an easter egg.

Answer (score 3):

I really liked **lolcat**:

```
sudo apt-get install lolcat
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | lolcat
```

Hint: rainbows.

---

Back on the ASCII art vein there is **toilet**:

```
sudo apt-get install toilet
echo abcdef | toilet
```

`man toilet` reveals a wealth of options.

---

Some of **bsdgames** could be classified as Easter eggs:

```
sudo apt-get install bsdgames
pom
number 123
primes 1 100
```

but the most part are just too awesome to be just Easter eggs.

---

**sudo Default insults**:

- `sudo visudo`
- Add a line `Defaults insults`

Now whenever you make a password mistake, `sudo` makes witty remarks about your intelligence or typing skills.

Learnt from [Network World](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2926630/linux/11-pointless-but-awesome-linux-terminal-tricks.html). All others on their top 11 were already here :-)

Comment: How does the `lolcat` command really work? I'm only getting colored text with the command you posted.

Comment: Hmm, are you familiar with `cat`? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29 `lolcat`'s a parody.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, I knew what `cat` was, I just thought that there was more to it.

Answer (score 2):

**`ddate`** is short for Discordian calendar, which was the calendar of an old cult that worshipped the Greek god of chaos, Eris (thanks @tox123).

I noticed this when mistyping the `date`. In a terminal, run

```
ddate
```

> Today is Sweetmorn, the 13th day of Discord in the YOLD 3181

Comment: It's not mistyped it is short for Discordian calendar, which was the calendar of an old cult that worshipped the greek god of chaos, eris.

Answer (score 2):

- Open System Settings (`unity-control-center` if using Unity or `gnome-control-center` if using GNOME)
- Click on "Mouse & Touchpad"
- Click on "Test Your Settings"
- Scroll to the top of the image: you'll see a nice kite
- Scroll to the bottom of the image; click on the inner circle five times (quickly); you'll see that the text below the circles changes
- Quickly scroll to the top of the image again!

Answer (score 1):

[**nmap** [image: Install nmap]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nmap) has one too, to format output in `s|<rIpt kIddi3` style:

```
$ nmap -oS - scanme.nmap.org

$taRt1ng Nmap 6.40 ( hTtp://nMap.org ) at 2015-03-27 19:22 C3T
NMap sCaN report F0r $cAnm3.nmap.Org (74.207.244.221)
H0$t !z up (0.17z laT3ncy).
N0T Shown: 995 f|ltEr3D p0Rt$
P0RT     $TaTE  s3RvIC3
80/tcP   op3n   htTp
443/Tcp  cl0$ed HtTps
6667/tcp cl0$3d 1Rc
6969/tcp Cl0S3d acmS0da
8333/TCp cl0seD unknOwn

Nmap Done: 1 iP addreSz (1 ho$t Up) scannEd !n 10.14 S3cONdz
```

Answer (score 1):

Unicode U+E0FF is displayed as the "Circle Of Friends" logo and U+F200 is "ubuntu" in the Ubuntu (typeface) on Ubuntu. Type: Ctrl-Shift-U, then F200 or E0FF in Gedit or Pluma. The characters are in the Unicode Private Use Area so they may display differently depending on which font you have selected. Here are both, they don't display on askubuntu.com, copy/paste to your regular text editor:

```
U+E0FF: 
U+F200: 
```

A screenshot:

> [image: Ubuntu Unicode Private Use Area]