# What Easter eggs are there in Unity?

Tags: unity, easter-egg

Are there any Easter Eggs in Unity?

The [Easter Eggs from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12336/easter-eggs-in-ubuntu)  involving <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (as provided by gnome-panel) don't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easter eggs in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12336/easter-eggs-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 20):

The only one up to now that I have found is this one:

[image]

Comment: ( ppa:dylanmccall/indicator-fish )

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, `about:robots` is another one

[image: about:robots screenshot]

Comment: This links to the Firefox easter egg, clicking on "Robots have a plan." will take you to `about:robots` in Firefox.

Answer (score 12):

There is also this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

and about:config is the last one ... it's just a link to CCSM if it's installed. (Obviously derived from Firefox)

Comment: it's not really an easter egg :(

Comment: @Alaukik I disagree. about:config is not the normal way to start CCSM by any means.

Comment: it is a usefull shortcut which opens ccsm with the unity configuration .