# How do I stop the 'Free the Fish' Easter Egg?

Tags: gnome, easter-egg

I did 'apt-get install free the fish' to see what the Ubuntu 'Wanda the Fish' Easter Egg looks like. I have now had enough of the fish and want it to stop, which I could do by logging in and out.

Unfortunately I have a few other things open right now and I don't want to do that. I tried ps -ef | more to see if I could identify the process, but I could not. Also the Google came up with no answers. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then paste `pkill gnome-panel` and your panel will disappear and reappear but the fish will be gone.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your speedy reply. New here so I cannot mod up your answer but it is the right one!

Comment: you have to click the currently grey tick button  and it will accept this as the right answer . see this (http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer  )

Answer (score -2):

You can also click on the fish. this will cause it to swim away to the nearest screen edge and disappear.

Comment: And re-appear after a while.