# Super Cow Powers?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easter eggs in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12336/easter-eggs-in-ubuntu)

I did "apt-get --help" and at the end of the output it said "This APT has Super Cow Powers."  I have never seen this message before.  Can anyone tell me what it means?  Thanks ahead of time for your input.

Comment: And my aptitude does *not* have super cow powers

Comment: Actually aptitude has super duper cow farm powers. Do this aptitude -v moo. Afterwards starting adding V's like aptitude -vvv moo and keep doing this until "something" happens.

Comment: @user18432 - please accept answers to questions you ask.  In several of your past questions, you in a comment say thanks.  Clicking the little check button is the best way to thank people from contributing to your questions.

Comment: @jokerdino, jrg You should probably add this as an answer to the "duplicate" question now. There's currently no mention on that page of what was asked about here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It appears to be a joke.

According to Wikipedia's [article on aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29#Easter_egg), apt-get contains an [easter egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29) resembling [cowsay](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man6/cowsay.6.html) that can be found by issuing the `moo` command:

```
$ apt-get moo
         (__)
         (oo)
   /------\/
  / |    ||
 *  /\---/\
    ~~   ~~
...."Have you mooed today?"...
```

The line in its help output,

```
$ apt-get --help | grep 'Super Cow Powers'
                       This APT has Super Cow Powers.
```

is presumably a reference to this easter egg, or perhaps was added later to parallel aptitude's claim that it ["does not have Super Cow Powers"](http://www.eeggs.com/items/43172.html).

Comment: OK, Thanks for the information.  I understand now.

Comment: @user18432 Since this answers your question, please accept this answer by clicking the check mark button to the left of the answer.

Comment: Interestingly, `aptitude moo` spits out: `There are no Easter Eggs in this program.`