# Why does aptitude give me the "Does not have Super Cow Powers" error?

Tags: aptitude, easter-egg

When I try to update 11.10 with current updates, I receive this error message stating Does Not Have Super Cow Powers. Why is it not updating with the current security packages?

Comment: Are you  putting sudo first e.g. sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade ?

Comment: Yes I am putting sudo in front.

Comment: it happens when aptitude dist-upgrade is ran. This ran fine until the most current security patches need to be installed.

Comment: Have you tries apt-get instead e.g. sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade ?

Comment: have you tried "apt-get" instead? I also have an issue with the code you expressed

Comment: Please post the *exact* command you ran and the *entire* output that you got from `aptitude`.

Comment: Without @James answering Iain's question, I don't think this question will be useful to anyone ever, therefore I am proposing it is closed.

Comment: A Google search reveals that quite a few users are confused about why `aptitude` says `This aptitude does not have Super Cow Powers`. I've posted what I hope is a good canonical answer to that question. Since that was the main question here and I was able to answer it, I don't think this question should be closed. Furthermore, while there are a number of easter eggs in Ubuntu, this easter egg (in Ubuntu and every system with `aptitude`) seems to be a particular source of confusion, so I don't think this question should be marked a duplicate of any general easter eggs question either.

Answer (score 14):

When you run `aptitude` with an unrecognized command or with the `--help` flag, you get [a screen briefly describing all the kinds of operations `aptitude` can perform](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1020281/). At the end, it says:

```
This aptitude does not have Super Cow Powers.
```

Since you're getting this text (the whole thing, not just the Super Cow Powers thing) while presumably trying to perform some real operation, this means you've mistyped your command. We can't give you more specific information unless you show us exactly what you're entering into the Terminal to produce this message.

**This is not about the Super Cow Powers. That's just the final line of the long message you get when you tell `aptitude` to do something it doesn't know how to do.**

While I cannot tell you exactly what you should have typed because I don't know what you *did* type, I *can* provide more information about Super Cow Powers, which hopefully will address the confusion surrounding this (intentionally silly) term.

Super Cow Powers is a term for an [easter egg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12336/easter-eggs-in-ubuntu) in [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) (see also [APT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)). There are related easter eggs in [aptitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29). See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28virtual%29) and [this other article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29#Easter_egg).

```
ek@Apok:~$ apt-get moo
         (__) 
         (oo) 
   /------\/ 
  / |    ||   
 *  /\---/\ 
    ~~   ~~
...."Have you mooed today?"...
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude moo
There are no Easter Eggs in this program.
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude -v moo
There really are no Easter Eggs in this program.
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude -vv moo
Didn't I already tell you that there are no Easter Eggs in this program?
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude -vvv moo
Stop it!
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude -vvvv moo
Okay, okay, if I give you an Easter Egg, will you go away?
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude -vvvvv moo
All right, you win.

                               /----\
                       -------/      \
                      /               \
                     /                |
   -----------------/                  --------\
   ----------------------------------------------
ek@Apok:~$ aptitude -vvvvvv moo
What is it? It's an elephant being eaten by a snake, of course.
```

What it means to say that [`aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aptitude.8.html) does not have Super Cow Powers is that it does not have the ability to display the Super Cow displayed when you run `apt-get moo`. This is one of the very few capabilities present in `apt-get` but not in `aptitude`. **;-)**

> Source:
>   https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+question/160087

Comment: That is a reference to "The Little Prince" by Antoine de Saint Exupery http://i.stack.imgur.com/iyx1a.jpg