# Panel applet ascii man

Tags: panel, ascii-art

what is this [little guy's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHKJd.jpg) name and how do I get him? [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12336/easter-eggs-in-ubuntu) was unhelpful because no one brings him up.